# How to use calculated fields to pull up "Grand Total" in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-named-ranges

I have a grand total value that I want to use in my calculated field. Instead of using a specific number like `=sum(impr./919)`, I want something like `=sum(impr./"grand total")` and that the grand total relates to a certain cell.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: what is `impr./` ?

Answer (score 0):

- select cell or range of cells
- go to **Data**
- select **Named ranges...**
- type in "**Grand_Total**"
- use formula **`=SUM(Grand_Total)`** instead of **`=SUM(A1:B3)`**

[image: 9]

Comment: To be more specific, in the pivot table, when im creating a calculated field I enter: =SUM(Impr./('Grand_total')) it doesnt work. =SUM(Impr./919) works perfectly but that is a static formula. And how do I use (grand_total) when i am relating it to a specific range?

Comment: @KelvinLee try `=SUM(Impr./grand_total)`